# Chroot syntax in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, environment-variables, chroot, env

I'm trying to debug a Makefile which at face value calls a script trying to `chroot` into some directory. Then it also does `env` command.

```
BCMD= bash

CMD= "/build/toolcrib/prepare_final_tree >crumbs/Final-prep.out 2>&1"

${BCMD} -c "chroot /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib /tools/bin/env -i ${CMD}"
```

I understand that it is chrooting into the specified directory.
What is it doing with the `env -i ${CMD}`, as a single command with chroot.

After I run this command it does not find the `/tools/bin/env` command.

Comment: Prepend a `pwd`  in `CMD`  definition

Comment: How? can you explain please.. where is PWD involved here ?

Comment: I'd worry a lot about a makefile trying to use `chroot`; I wouldn't use it.

Comment: THe Makefile calls a script which runs these commands. Edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `/tools/bin/env` is not installed correctly in your chroot. It may be missing or some of its dependencies may be missing.

Perhaps the chroot has a `/usr/bin/env` that you could use instead.

You might be able to find what other files are missing for `env` to work by running `ldd` from outside the chroot:

```
ldd /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/tools/bin/env
```

However it might be best to properly install `coreutils` into your chroot.

Comment: /tools/bin/ contains env, I copied is from my (non chrooted) /usr/bin/env.

Comment: What is the exact output of `chroot /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib /tools/bin/env` and `ls -l /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/tools/bin/env`?

Comment: 1. chroot: failed to run command ‘/tools/bin/env’: No such file or directory


2. `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26308 Dec  8 17:27 /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/tools/bin/env`

Comment: I believe the "No such file or directory" error is generated when looking for dynamically linked libraries. You can list those by doing `ldd /home/user/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/tools/bin/env`.